# How to filter data in a report using Microsoft Report Builder based on Orders of Service (OS) dates?

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a task using Report Builder to create reports where I need to filter data based on dates related to Orders of Service (OS).

I am using parameters @StartDate and @EndDate to allow the user to select a date range to filter the data.

How can I adjust the datasets to include the necessary WHERE clauses to correctly filter the data based on the dates of the Orders of Service (OS) associated with each contractor, contract, and lot?

SELECT *
FROM Company
WHERE RegistrationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @DateFim and @EndDate.

Comment: BETWEEN only takes to values `BETWEEN @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime` you seem to be passing it 3? Edit your question and explain the logic and where @DateFim fits into it?